# how to contribute body of modal in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The requirement-My applicaiton has a button which when clicked a modal is supposed to pop-up where there will contain some data.
Architecture-I want the modal data to be contributed from some another application(some url),through a php file.How can this be done?

What I have tried-In the php file i have placed

```
<?php echo ' <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the html I am using this

```
<div id="prerequisites-container" class="container-fluid">
    <a href="http://localhost/Experiment/main/prereq.php"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">
        Launch Modal </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your HTML code, as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

inside your Echo.

```
<?php echo ' HERE <div class="modal-dialog">
```

**UPDATED:**

```
<div id="prerequisites-container" class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trymodalbootstrap" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default">Launch Modal</a>
</div>

<?php echo '<div class="modal fade" id="trymodalbootstrap" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but that is exactly what I am doing in the current scenario and its not working

Comment: I updated my answer. pls see that and it works in my localhost page. if it doesn't work, perhaps, you forgot to add bootstrap links

Comment: I saw you give a link inside the caller. you can change it into button instead of <a> if you need to redirect to an external page, then you don't need bootstrap modal

Comment: thanks it works,what I did is along with your solution I punched @khanmizan solution.Together it works fine.However I have to chose only one best ans,so I would choose urs considering the efforts.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

place the modal html in your html, and fetch modal content data dynamically through ajax call from server. and add that data to modal before displaying